# Why is this template expansion legal in C++?

Tags: c++, templates, generics, types, template-argument-deduction

Consider the following code:

```
template <typename T>
void foo(const T& param) {
    std::cout << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << std::endl;
    std::cout << param;
}

int main()
{
    foo<const int&>(5);
    return 0;
}
```

The output gives:

```
void foo(const T&) [with T = const int&]                                                                                                                       
5
```

Here apparently `T` is resolved to `const int&` (as the printout says, since I explicitly forced so). However, this seems to create a problem: The function signature takes a parameter of type `const T&`, and in this case it would expand to `const const int& &`, which is not legal syntax in C++.

But the program indeed runs fine. What's going on here?

Update:
I know that `T& &` would collapse to `T&`. However, in this case, the double `const` is also not legal if you write them explicitly, and I don't see that template collapsing rule mention this part.

Update 2:
Compiling `const const int x = 1;` gives `error: duplicate ‘const’`. Multiple const is not allowed in c++ (but surprisingly in c it's okay).

Comment: `T` isn't "resolved"; you explicitly give it the argument `const int&`

Answer (score 5):

C++ types are not formed by textual replacement. `const T&` where `T` is `void *` is `void* const &`, not `const void *&`.

Your code attempts to form the type "lvalue reference to `const T`" where `T` is "lvalue reference to `const int`". By [the reference collapsing rules](https://wg21.link/dcl.ref#6), that will instead form the type "lvalue reference to `const int`".

Comment: Worth noting what happens if you do have redundant `const` on the same layer, though, for example `const T` where `typedef const int T`